# Pagination Firestor CollectionView Swift Programmatically

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, collectionview

Regarding Pagination with Firestore I followed the guide on their [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?authuser=0) and on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU) but I don't understand one thing:

Practically speaking, if we have a `collectionView` displaying cells from a first query of 10 documents.
We scroll to the bottom of the `collectionView` when all the data of the first query have been visible, where do we call the next query from the controller?

I searched online but didn't find much, I was thinking maybe with some delegate methods of `UIScrollViewDelegate` of the `CollectionView` (?) but It doesn't seem to offer the right methods to do that.

Also for better user experience I was thinking that is better to call the next query when the user is approaching the bottom of the collection and not when he already reached it.

Comment: `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if newInstrumentList.count-1 == indexPath.row && isMoreDataAvailable{
        self.presenter?.showMorePage()
    }
}
```

This is what is use for pagination, generally during an API call I get the total number of item and depending on that I set a bool property. Whenever the collection view cell index matches with the indexPath.row, next data is requested.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean with ```get the total number of item```, you firstly make an api call to get all the documents first?

Comment: No you don't get all the documents first. This is what pagination is for, you just get the total  `number`  of documents or files. You need to know how many items are there, how many are loaded. If there are no more documents, it won't make sense to make a network call to request for more elements.

Comment: But by knowing the total number of documents doesn't it mean that We're already reading them firsthand?